# Esri map not displayed in android

Tags: android, arcgis-android

In my android application I add a new feature to a feature layer after processing data in various activities, feature layer is updated but when I return to the main activity to display updated feature layer neither map nor feature layer is displayed In  the log cat I found
com.esri.core.io.EsriServiceException: Request Time-out

Comment: Are you testing the app through the AVD or on your actual device?

Comment: By genymotion emulator

Comment: Can you share some code?